# " Invalid domain: URL must be hosted on a domain listed in the "Authorized domains" section. "

Tags: api, oauth

I'm trying to set up an OAuth client in Google API but keep getting the following message:

"Invalid domain: URL must be hosted on a domain listed in the "Authorized domains" section. "

What do I do? I already verified the domain.